# How to create multi column list/vector using c++

Tags: c++, list, vector

I have a list of filenames,their size,file path,their CRC32.Now I want to place them in a list/vector with each one(filename,size,file path) in a separate column.

I have tried with multidimensional vector but in that case each value is independent on each other.

Kindly suggest on how to accomplish this task?
Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Ravi

Comment: Make a struct containing all this information and make a vector of that struct? Your question isn't exactly clear to me.

Comment: Thanks borgleader.I have  the information of the file(name,path,size,crc32).Now I have multiple files and I want to store them in a particular Data structure and then find duplicates from them depending upon the name/size/crc32.

Comment: @user3264565 You've got an answer to proceed with, try something with it, show some efforts and if you're _really_ lost come back at SO. Don't simply ask us to write codes for you.

Comment: @POW I have already written vector(single dimension) code to find duplicates.All I wanted was how to place multiple values in a vector/list.I just wanted the way to accomplish this.Not the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct File {
  std::string FileName;
  std::string Path;
  size_t Size;
  std::uint32_t CRC32;
};
std::vector<File> file_vec ;
```